# How to control a View on selecting particular File Type in Eclipse Editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to control a view , like if I select a .js type of file , a particular view should be visible else for all other type it shouldn't.
I dont want to use perspective as for just a single selection, it will be an overhead.
Please suggest me any way to achieve the same through Eclipse plug-in Development.

Comment: Are you creating your own RCP application, or you mean you want to contribute a view to the Eclipse IDE?

Comment: I'm expecting on selection of .JS file , different set of views must open and ViceVersa with .HTML file. but this above scenario must not hold with Perspective ....and this is for plug-in development(contributing to eclipse) nt RCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you contribute the view, you either don't mention a perspective (in which case when the view is shown it defaults to the bottom right) or you use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point to contribute it to a specific location.  You can make it visible or invisible by default.

You make the view visible/invisible at runtime using the `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchCommandConstants.VIEWS_SHOW_VIEW` command and the view ID parameter, or by using the showView(*)/hideView(*) API in `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage`

See [Plugging into the Workbench](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench.htm) for more information.